# add a comment and a new line after a matching text

Tags: unix, sed

I have following line in my profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
```

how can I comment this line and add a new line after this line.

expected result:

```
#export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
export JAVA_HOME=${java_path}
```

I have tried this

I tried the following `sed -e '/export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java/ s/^#*/#/' < file.txt` to add the comment only if it doesn't exist, but that isn't working

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this problem?

Comment: I tried the following

sed -e '/export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java/ s/^#*/#/' < file.txt 

to add the comment only if it doesnt exist, but that isn't working.

Comment: Please click "edit" and put that in the question instead of a comment.

Comment: @MO12: I personally don't think your question merits down-votes, but they presumably stem from your initially perceived lack of effort. It helps everyone if you show _up-front_ what you've tried, what, specifically, didn't work, and how it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (assumes ***GNU* Sed**):

```
sed -r '\|^(export JAVA_HOME=)/usr/bin/java$| {s//#&\n\1${java_path}/}' file.txt
```

With ***BSD (OSX)* Sed** (should also work with GNU Sed), things get a little more complicated (assumes `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh` as the shell, due to use of `$'\n'`, an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting), to produce a literal newline char.):

```
sed -E '\|^(export JAVA_HOME=)/usr/bin/java$| {s//#&\'$'\n''\1${java_path}/;}' file.txt
```

A (hopefully) **POSIX-compliant solution** (yet a little more complicated; also  assumes `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh` as the shell):

```
sed '\|^\(export JAVA_HOME=\)/usr/bin/java$| {s//#&\'$'\n''\1${java_path}/;}' file.txt
```

<sup>As you can see, different `sed` implementations require different solutions, so, especially with `sed` and `awk`, but with Unix utilities in general, it's advisable to mention one's platform OR to explicitly request a cross-platform-compatible solution.</sup>

Note: Usually, `/.../` is used to delimit regular expressions in Sed commands, but it is possible to choose a different delimiter, which is helpful if you want to avoid having to escape `/` chars. in the regex itself. Here, I've chosen `|` - note that the *opening* `|` must be `\`-escaped (which you do *not* have to do when choosing an alternate delimiter for `s///`).

---

As for **why your command**, `sed -e '/export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java/ s/^#*/#/' < file.txt`, **didn't work**:

- You neglected to escape the `/` chars. in the regex as `\/`, which is necessary, given that your Sed address uses `/` as the regex *delimiters*.
- `s/^#*/#/` looks for zero or more *existing* `#` chars on the matching line, and replaces them with just `#` - under the given circumstances, a no-op.

  - If you want the `s` function to operate implicitly on what the context address (the regex at the start of the script that selects matching lines) matched, you must use an *emtpy* regex, i.e., `s//.../`, as in the solution above.
  - To refer to the matched text in the substitution text, you must use `&`; if there are capture groups, as in the solution above, you can refer to what they captured by index: `\1` refers to the 1st group, ...

Comment: Thank You, that worked. I did a `sed -i.bak` to backup exisitng file and also ran the command multiple times to make sure it doesnt append the same line again and again.